# Django prevent direct url access

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Lets say I have

.decs

```
def unwelcome_user(unwelcome_roles=[]):
        def decorator(view_func):
            def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
                if request.user.is_authenticated:
                    for group in request.user.groups.all():
                        if group.name in unwelcome_roles:
                            return redirect('main:unwelcome-user-type', 
                                             user_type=group.name)
                        else:
                            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper_func
        return decorator
```

.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('error-unwelcome/<str:user_type>', views.unwelcome_user, name='success')
]
```

.views

```
@unwelcome_user(unwelcome_roles=['xyz'])
def success(request) 
    return render(request, 'success_page.html', {})

def unwelcome_user(request, user_type):
return render(request, 'errors/unwelcome_user.html', {})
```

I can access the unwelcome_user view directly by typing something like mysite.com/error-unwelcome/xyz in the browser even without going through the subsequent process that should result in showing that page.
How do I prevent that?

Comment: What is the process to reach the success page exactly?

Comment: This was just an example. In reality, I have a decorator that checks if the user who requested a certain view is in a certain user group, if not, an 'error' view is called

Answer (score 2):

I'm still new to Django so I couldn't try out the cookie/sessions answers given (I still have to learn sessions). In the meantime, here's what I'm using:

```
def get_referer(request):
    referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if not referer:
        return None
    return referer
```

then in any view

```
def my_view(request):
    if not get_referer(request):
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'sample.html', {})
```

Here I'm assuming that if there's no referer, then it means the person typed in the URL into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is part of a chain of pages for the user to navigate, you will need to pass some state when moving from one page to the next. You can either use a cookie and check the value of the cookie in the view, or pass a GET query parameter:

```
def success(request):
  token = request.GET.get('token', None)

  if token is None or not Token.objects.filter(value=token).exists():
    return redirect(...) # previous step or beginning

  return render(...) # page
```

Previous pages should create this token. Then pass it in the URL:

```
/success/?token=<token>
```

Comment: I see the logic,. but I'm still a beginner in django and I wouldnt know how to generae that token/cookie

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

The process_page will only render success.html if `your_subsequent_process()` returns a `True`, otherwise, the process.html will be rendered.

```
def proces_page(request):
    """Your Process View"""
    
    if your_subsequent_process():
        return render(request, 'success.html', {})

    return render(request, 'proces.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [sessions [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions). If you are redirecting a user to the page, before redirecting just add a variable to the session indicating that they can access the view.

So just before the redirect:

```py
request.session['is_unwelcome'] = True
return redirect('main:unwelcome-user-type', user_type=group.name)
```

In the view you would simply check whether the variable is present in the session:

```py
def unwelcome_user(request, user_type):
    if 'is_unwelcome' not in request.session:
        # Redirect or raise Http 404?
        # return redirect('somewhere')
        # raise Http404()
    del request.session['is_unwelcome']
    return render(request, 'errors/unwelcome_user.html', {})
```